# Unnumbered equations: Any difference between \begin{equation*} and \[?

Tags: equations

Is there a difference between defining an unnumbered equation with

Option 1:

```
\begin{equation*} ...  \end{equation*}
```

versus

Option 2:

```
\[ ...  \]
```

If there are differences, they are not apparent in my use of the commands.

Comment: Under [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), `\[` and `\]` are equivalent to `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}`. In [`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.dtx) you'll find `\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}`.

Comment: some users have stated a preference for the `\...{equation*}` form as it's easier to get rid of the `*` if it's decided that the display really should have a number than to type in the larger change.  otherwise, no functional difference.